# Excel Power Query: transform two cells into two duplicate rows

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I have an Excel Power Query that imports and transforms a CSV data-transfer file from what is essentially a timesheeting web application ready for importing into our payroll application, again via CSV. Certain rows have both ‘daytime’ and ‘night-time’ hours in two separate fields. I need to transform these two fields into two separate rows adding a custom ‘rate’ field for each. To illustrate:

```
Name               day hours      night hours
A.N Other               6              4
```

Transforms into:

```
Name               day hours      night hours    hours      rate
A.N Other               6              0           6        rate1
A.N Other               0              4           4        rate2
```

- The payroll application can only process ‘hours’ and ‘rate’ on individual rows
- I have gone through the full ‘M’ specification and nothing jumps out.
- I have googled and there’s lots of stuff about removing duplicates, not a lot about creating them!

To be honest, I don’t really know where to start. Any help would be warmly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key step here is to select the `day hours` and `night hours` columns in your query editor and choose `Unpivot Columns` under the `Transform` tab.

This will yield:

```
Name                Attribute      Value       
A.N Other           day hours        6
A.N Other          night hours       4
```

Once you do that you can create custom columns using the following rules:

```
if [Attribute] = "day hours" then [Value] else 0
```

and analogously for the night hours column:

```
if [Attribute] = "night hours" then [Value] else 0
```

From there you can rearrange, rename, and delete columns as desired.

You can also create a custom rate column with similar logic using the Attribute column or one of the hours columns.

Comment: The answer was staring me in the face! A perfect solution, warmly and gratefully received.